# Unsure about fixing "no matching function for call" error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble figuring out an error I'm getting.

Basically, I have an `unordered_map`, which maps `string` to `int`, and I'm trying to return the `string` using the `int`:

This is what I wrote:

```cpp
// for each int representations of neighbor nodes
for(long unsigned int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
    // return string representation of neighbor nodes
    std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::const_iterator got = umap.find(labels[i]);
    ret.push_back(got->first);
}
```

Where `ret` is a `vector` of strings, `labels` is a `vector` of ints, and `umap` is my `unordered_map<string,int>`.

The error I am getting is this:

> no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator, int>::value_type&)'

Comment: Aren’t your key and value types backwards everywhere (down to `->first` to get the answer you want)?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `unordered_map` backwards.

Your `unordered_map` is using `std::string` as its `key_type`, and `int` as its `mapped_type`.  That means it is indexing entries by strings, not by integers.

As such, `unordered_map::find()` takes in a `std::string` to search for, but you are passing in an `int` instead, hence the error.  You are trying to find an entry by its mapped value, but that is not how `find()` works.  It searches for an entry by its key instead.

The only way to search an `unordered_map` for a key given its mapped value is to iterate the entries manually. You can use [`std::find_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for that, eg:

```cpp
// for each int representations of neighbor nodes
for(size_t i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
    // return string representation of neighbor nodes
    int value = labels[i];
    auto got = std::find_if(umap.begin(), umap.end(),
        [=](const auto &elem){ return elem.second == value; }
    );
    if (got != umap.end())
        ret.push_back(got->first);
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to `find()` a `std::string` by an `int`, you need to use an `unordered_map<int, string>` instead of an `unordered_map<string, int>`.